How to style the group unsubscribe link in a Sendgrid Single Send where email content is set by API
I'm using the Sendgrid Single Send API and setting the html_content property and suppression_group_id property when creating a Single Send email.
How do I style the Unsubscribe From This List | Manage Email Preferences links that Sendgrid injects into the email content? I want these links to appear in the email, but want them styled to match my email content.
I've tried adding <%asm_group_unsubscribe_url%> to my email content which according to the docs should be substituted for the unsubscribe/manage preferences links, but it isn't working.

To format the unsubscribe and unsubscribe preferences links for a Single Send email created by API use the Reserved Substitution Tags and add them to the content passed to the html_content property. The tags {{unsubscribe}} and {{unsubscribe_preferences}} are urls. Including these substitution tags will replace the links that Sendgrid appends to the Single Send email.
Example of html with substitution tags passed in html_content that formats the unsubscribe links in a Single Send email:
<div className="text-xs text-center mt-6">
  <a href="{{unsubscribe}}">
    unsubscribe
  </a>
  {' '}|{' '}
  <a href="{{unsubscribe_preferences}}">
    manage subscription preferences
  </a>
</div>

